# GWT - Inject value using Guice @Named

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt2, guice-3

I have Utility class as below.

```
class Utility{
  @Inject
  @Named("endpoint")
  private String endpoint; //generated only getter
}
```

I am configuring value for endpoint in the as below.

```
public class ConfigModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("endpoint"))
    .to("Endpoint URL");
  }
}
```

In my GWT class I am trying to get this value.

```
public class MyUIPanel extends Composite {
  @Override
  protected void onLoad() {
    Window.Location.assign(new Utility().getEndpoint());
  }
}
```

UI loaded properly with error coming up in browser console saying **You are executing Names.named() in GWT code. GWT does not emulate enough of Java that will work.**

Also tried to inject Utility class in MyUIPanel class using guice but getting below error at the time of building war
**Binding requested for constant key Key[type=java.lang.String, annotation=@com.google.inject.name.Named(value=CognitoEndpoint)] but no explicit binding was found.**

Comment: Shouldn't `Utility` instantiated by Guice also in order to make `endpoint` be properly injected?

Comment: Tried that too. But it's not working.

Comment: @AlexeyR. edited the question with error I am getting for injecting Utility using Guice

Comment: How do you tell Guice to use `ConfigModule` to resolve injections?

Comment: In implementation of GuiceServletContextListener I am injecting all classes using Guice.createInjector()

Comment: AFAIK, you can not use Guice on the client. That's what the message is telling you. Try Dagger on the client side or just use a Factory or something else ...

Comment: I have used RPC to get value from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out Guice cannot be used on client side.

To fetch static values inside our GWT Client Code, we can bind those values inside class extending **AbstractGinModule** class.

To fetch dynamic values from properties files, write logic on server side and get values on client side using GWT RPC.

Comment: I would suggest to not use GIN, as it is no longer under active development and is not J2CL compatible.

Comment: I am not sure. I am new to GWT. I recently joined the project and found out GIN is already implemented and I am not allowed to change it.